# Postgres database growing (a lot) without any insert

Tags: centos, database, postgresql

So I'm a student and I'm used to create database, make queries to extract data from  it or insert some and so on, but I don't have any knowledge about maintenance. I searched for some informations on the net, but it didn't answered my problem or was too difficult for me.

Here is the thing : The database I work on has millions of lines, and every time I run a SELECT query, it get bigger and way slower, so I need to find why in order to stop it because I'm running out of space and some really slow queries can take hours to finish.

[image: df -h on the database]

It was about 25Go last week, already 33 now, but I think it shouldn't get bigger than 10Go for all the data it contains, and I really don't have any clues about what is happening.

[image: du -sh /var/lib/*]

Some threads talk about logs files but I don't think it could get that big that fast, some other about OID but even if I don't really know what this is they are set on "OFF" on this database so I'm quiet lost.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's the error when trying to view the pgsql directory?

Comment: It says "no files or directory of this type"

Comment: Did you have a look at the latest change dates? Why do you expect it to not get bigger than 10 GB? What kind of queries are you running? Does it really increase with every query? If so, by how much?

Comment: Well I don't really know, there are a lot of files in the folder, some are the same since 19 of November and maybe half of it was updated since last week. The weird thing is that it grows with SELECT queries, and like several GB per day ! I do not know if it is the same for every query, it is difficult to test as lot of them run for hour before failing (server disconnected as result)

Comment: Check what queries are being ran. Maybe you are create views, setting up locks that don't get released, temporary tables etc.

Comment: I have no idea of what views and locks are, so I quickly checked on google and it doesn't seem that it can be created implicitely : for example it says that you have to write "CREATE VIEW" to make one.
Is there a way to realease all those temporary things or even know what is stored away from the table ?